# How do I change the outgoing number on google voice?

Tags: phone, google-voice, caller-id

I used to use Google FI with Google Voice, but recently changed carriers.

I relinked my number to Google Voice, and it now shows up in the "My Devices" section.

For whatever reason, Google Voice also requires that you create another number in order to use it (which I did), but now all outgoing calls are made from this new number.

How do I change the outgoing number to the one I linked?

Comment: Hogs are not bad. Maybe try https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Gantendo google voice is not just a web app